# Disabling or masking read-only text field highlighting or selection through CSS?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to disable or mask selected text in a read-only text box using only CSS? I am creating a form using an online form builder that lets me append CSS before the form. I already made the text in the read-only text box "invisible" by making it white to blend in with the background, but if someone hits Ctrl+A to select everything on the page, they are able to read the highlighted text which I don't want them to be able to do. I would like to either block them from being able to highlight text in the read-only text box, or to make the text color while highlighting to be the same color as the highlight color.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `user-select` property to `none` for all the `read-only` fields:

```
*:read-only, [readonly],[type='readonly'] {
  color:transparent;
  -webkit-user-select:none;
  -moz-user-select:none;
  -ms-user-select:none;
  user-select:none;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UeRL4/10/)

**PS**: All other browsers supports `:read-only` selector well **except** the so-called FireFox, so we have to work-around a little by using the attribute selector.

Comment: Firefox doesn't support the `:read-only` pseudo class. Better method would use `disabled` instead of `readonly`. EDIT: Misread the original question, and the OP is specifically asking about `read-only`, so while the above is important, your answer is still completely correct.

Comment: FF understands pointer-events, make a mix of the two answers :)

Comment: @AndyM thanks for the info, I corrected by using the attribute selector instead

Answer (score 2):

give a look at `pointer-events` in CSS to disallow mouse interaction.

`<input type="readonly"  class="pointernone" value="readonly + pointer-events:none"/>`

`.pointernone {pointer-events:none;}`

no way to click for a CTRL-A if browser understands pointer-events *(.. old IEs ? , well :) )*

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ErwJn/